# API to adjust screen color temperature Win RT

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I see f.lux (desktop app) change the screen color temperature on Win 7.So I wonder if there is a way to do this in Win RT (just Metro style app)?

I've tried searching on google but I couldn't find anything related information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this in WinRT. The api does not provide any functionality to do this, it is very restrictive.

Comment: Thanks. But is it like ios? I mean I have to hack Surface RT device to use private WinRT API to adjust screen color temperature like private iOS API.

Comment: Yes, it is locked like iOS. The applications do not get access to the underlying system, they're sandboxed. It's for security reasons, and I think it's good that way (personal opinion). :-)